# DataGrid thousand seperator WPF in .CS file

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I need to add thousand seperator for DataGrid column in WPF. I'm binding data to the grid in .cs file.

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = data;
```

In xaml file I'm not defining the columns.

```
<DataGrid Name="DgReplenish" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" Grid.Row="0" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}">
        </DataGrid>
```

How can I set thosand seperator to 3rd column in grid after binding data?
For example if the value is 15650 I want to show that as 15,650.

Comment: your question is not clear, could you please provide some more detail

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by "thousand separator"?  Do you want to place a column that will have a value of 1000 in every row?  Do you want a column 1000 pixels wide?  Please clarify.  Thanks

Comment: Edited the question. Please check

Answer (score 1):

Set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` on your `DataGrid` and define each column individually. Then you have more control over each column, e.g. you can specify the number format. In order to display the thousands separator, use `N0` for `StringFormat`.

Here is an example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication11.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- This is just some sample data: -->
        <x:Array x:Key="DemoData" Type="{x:Type Point}">
            <Point X="1234" Y="1234"/>
            <Point X="33" Y="33"/>
            <Point X="444444" Y="444444"/>
            <Point X="0" Y="0"/>
        </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{StaticResource DemoData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="X (without separators)" Binding="{Binding X}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Y (with separators)" Binding="{Binding Y, StringFormat=N0}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

It looks like this:

[image: Screen shot]